# Javascript- creating element as a child of another element

Tags: javascript, html

Hello here's my simple code.I want to display image created in `function add(src){}` in element `main_container`.Why doesn't it work?

```
 <head>
 </head>

 <body>

  <style>

#main_container
{
 width:1000px;
 height:1000px;
 position:absolute;
 border-style:solid;
}

.jersey
{
 width:100px;
 height:150px;
 position:absolute;
}

  </style>

<script>
var dist=-110;

function add(src)
{
  dist=dist+110;

 var img=document.createElement("img");
 img.src=src;
 img.style.left=dist+"px";
 img.className="jersey";

 document.getElementById("main_container").appendChild(img);
}

  add("http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg");

</script>

 <div id="main_container"></div>

 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the script tag below the element.

Change:

```
<script>...</script>
<div id="main_container"></div>
```

To:

```
<div id="main_container"></div>
<script>...</script>
```

The browser reads HTML from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

beautifulcoder's suggested modification should work, and he is absolutely correct that this is happening because the `main_container` DOM element will not yet be loaded if it appears after the `<script>`, but ideally, you should hold off on making DOM manipulations until the document has loaded. You can do this by using the `window.onload` event:

```
<script>
    function add(src) {
       ...
    }

    function initialize() {
        add("http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg");
    }

    window.onload = initialize;
</script>
<div id="main_container"></div>
```

or even better, use jQuery's `ready` event:

```
function initialize() {
    add("http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg");
}

$(document).ready(initialize);

//   $(initialize);   <- Shorthand version
```

Either of these approaches will free you from having to worry about where your script blocks are relative to your page elements.